# Write javascript as innerHTML of document.getElementById function

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

i dont know a lot of javascript but one thing ive realized is doing this

```
function example()
{
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML="<script>document.write(example)</script>"
}
```

doesnt work! i understand this but is there another way of doing this same thing that does work?

Comment: You can not use `document.write` after page load either. Well you can, it is just going to blow up the page and make it a new one.

Comment: **Why** do you want to **write** *JavaScript code* in an element? Specifically, the function that this code is in?

Comment: because i need the content to be added after user input, which activates the function. and it need to be javascript because its a varioable that i want adding

Comment: Could you add a more complete example of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

This approach worked for me:

```
<body>
    <div id="main">
    </div>

    <script>
    // create a script element
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    // fill its inner html with js code
    script.innerHTML = 'alert("Javascript");'
    // add it inside your target div and then profit!
    document.getElementById('main').appendChild(script);
    </script>
</body>
```

Edit:
I've found more info about your problem here, I suggest you read the question, it has plenty of helpful answers and it also explains why your first approach did not work: [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)

A simple vanilla approach of using this code to write data inside a div after the page has loaded could be done like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.innerHTML = 'alert("Javascript");'
            document.getElementById('main').appendChild(script);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could i use this approach for getting it to write into a div after the page has loaded? it doesnt seem to be working

Comment: yep, you can, check my answer again, I've added extra code

Comment: Awesome question and answer, saved me lots of time for writing a chartjs to JavaScript object inside the View in MVC.

Answer (score -1):

There is two error on your script. This is doesn't work, because variable name and function name equal to div id and this wrong method for javascript. You write a code to your div, but you don't run it. You can try that;

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<script>
function example()
{
document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = eval("document.write('lololo')");
}
example();
</script>
```

Comment: this workes but overwrites the page with the value. i want the value as innerhtml of the div